# Location Permission Screen showing white blank in React Native Expo project with no error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In *MainMapScreen.js* I want the users to show a location permissions prompt once they click on the button. If they have allowed location, I want to show the *map.js* component.

The *map.js* screen works fine and fetches the data from the Firestore database correctly.

But the *MainMapScreen.js* shows completely blank with no error

**MainMapScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import Map from './Map';

const LocationPermission = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLocationPermission();
  }, []);

  const checkLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        getCurrentLocation();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        getCurrentLocation();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
    try {
      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
        timeout: 15000,
      });

      const { latitude, longitude } = location.coords;
      setLocation({ latitude, longitude });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {location ? (
        <Map latitude={location.latitude} longitude={location.longitude} />
      ) : (
        <View>
          <Text>Location not allowed</Text>
          <Button style={{backgroundColor: blue}} title="Request Location Permission" onPress={requestLocationPermission} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default LocationPermission;
```

**map.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker, Callout } from 'react-native-maps';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../config/firebase';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Maps = ({ latitude, longitude }) => {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMarkers = async () => {
      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'bars'));
        const newMarkers = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));
        setMarkers(newMarkers);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching markers:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchMarkers();
  }, [isFocused]);

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: latitude || 37.78825,
          longitude: longitude || -122.4324,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
      >
        {markers.map(marker => (
          <Marker
            key={marker.id}
            coordinate={{ latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude }}
            title={marker.name}
          >
            <Callout>
              <View>
                <Text>{marker.name}</Text>
              </View>
            </Callout>
          </Marker>
        ))}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Maps;
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "PissooV1",
    "slug": "PissooV1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your location is needed for..."
      },
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.thomasperr.PissooV1"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.thomasperr.PissooV1"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "4f72c53d-d551-4229-94d9-83e7933e2f5e"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
     

    ]
  }
}
```